# ob_get_clean - how to str_replace two variables?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, ob-start

At the top of my page I have a breadcrumb.

```
ob_start();
<li>##product##</li>
<li>##category##</li>
```

After this, I run mysql query to get the variables:

```
$product
$category
```

then I run:

```
<?php echo str_replace("##product##", $product, ob_get_clean())  ?>
<?php echo str_replace("##category##", $category, ob_get_clean())  ?>
```

The variable $product gets replaced and I see the second variable won't get replaced because ive called ob_get_clean()) already for product.

How can I replace both strings using the ob_get_clean function?

Comment: `str_replace(["##product##", "##category##"], [$product, $category, ob_get_clean()]);`

Comment: Why are you doing this? Run your query at the top of the page and generate your breadcrumb correctly in the first place.

Comment: U can define a callback function in `ob_start($callback)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the result of `ob_get_clean()` to a variable:

```
$ob = ob_get_clean();
$ob = str_replace("##product##", $product, $ob);
$ob = str_replace("##category##", $category, $ob);
echo $ob;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ob_get_contents instead of ob_get_clean.

```
$product = 'product 1';
$category = 'category1';
ob_start();
echo '<li>##product##</li>
      <li>##category##</li>';


$template = ob_get_contents();

$template = str_replace("##product##", $product, $template);
$template = str_replace("##category##", $category, $template);

ob_end_clean();
echo $template;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$find = array("##product##", "##category##");
$replace = array($product, $category);
echo str_replace($find, $product, ob_get_clean());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, you are replcing tho variables from one source.

Best you can do is:

```
$from = array("##product##", "##category##");
$to = array($product, $category);
echo str_replace($from, $to, ob_get_contents());
```

Or you can run several functions in one row. Notice `$replaced` is the same as Input and Output:

```
$replaced = ob_get_contents();
$replaced = str_replace("##product##", $product, $replaced);
$replaced = str_replace("##category##", $category, $replaced);
echo $replaced;
```

I thnk, it is effectively to use the first method, because you are calling it only once with data supply.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ob_get_contents()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) instead :

```
<?php echo str_replace("##product##", $product, ob_get_contents())  ?>
<?php echo str_replace("##category##", $category, ob_get_contents())  ?>
```

If you use [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), you delete output buffer after first call.

Answer (score 0):

`ob_get_clean()` essentially executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    echo str_replace("##product##", $product, ob_get_contents());
    echo str_replace("##category##", $category, ob_get_contents());
?>
```